# Python Pandas extract unique values from a column and another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am studying pandas, bokeh etc. to get started with Data Vizualisation. Right now I am practising with a giant table containing different birds. There are plenty of columns; two of those columns are "SCIENTIFIC NAME" and another one is "OBSERVATION COUNT".
I want to extract those two columns.

I did

```
df2 = df[["SCIENTIFIC NAME" , "OBSERVATION COUNT"]]
```

but the problem then is, that every entry is inside the table (since sometimes there are multiple entries/rows due to other columns of the same SCIENTIFIC NAME, but the OBSERVATION COUNT is always the same for the scientific name)

How can I get those two sectors but with the unique values, so every scientific name once, with the corresonding observation count.

EDIT:  I just realized that sometimes the same scientific names have different observation counts due to another column. Is there a way to extract every first unique item from a column

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, You can use `drop_duplicates`:

```
df2 = df[["SCIENTIFIC NAME" , "OBSERVATION COUNT"]].drop_duplicates()
```

To get counts:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["SCIENTIFIC NAME" , "OBSERVATION COUNT"])["SCIENTIFIC NAME"].count()
```

Comment: Hey there,

thanks for the quick answer, I just realized that sometimes the same scientific names have different observation counts due to another column.
Is there a way to extract every first unique item from a column

Comment: This works, but I also need to know the corresponding "observation count" value for this given scientific name. I need something that goes through all values in a column and saves the first entry of a new name and also the corresponding observation count.

Comment: It is better that you provide an example of your data frame and its expected output. We need to work using an example data frame to better understand what you want and test if the solution is correct.